# Methods around colorful numbers

Tags: ruby

I am supposed to write a method that returns `true` or `false` for `is_colorful_number?`

- 263 is a colorful number because (2, 6, 3, 2 x 6 = 12, 6 x 3 = 18, 2 x 6 x 3 = 36) are all different.
- 236 is not because (2, 3, 6, 2 x 3 = 6, 3 x 6 = 18, 2 x 3 x 6 = 36) have 6 twice.

It doesn't make sense. What am I missing?

Comment: Please state your question clearer. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I try to make it clearer next time. I DO know how to create the method tho.
My Issue ( which I tried to make clear by adding all the extra text) is that the concept of colorful numbers itself is not clear to me. 
The examples given do not make sense. 
And I was asking for an explanation of these.
Please restore my original post and I will try to make it more clear what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

=Given the number (as integer), extract the digit to an array then reverse:

```
number = 263
ary = number.digits.reverse #=> [2, 6, 3]
```

Now, [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) from 1 to array length [with object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) by [each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to get the array containing the products

```
products = ary.length.times.map.with_object([]) { |n, a| a.concat ary.each_cons(n+1).map { |e| e.reduce(&:*) } }
#=> [2, 6, 3, 12, 18, 36]
```

Finally check if products contains duplicates, for example:

```
products.size == products.uniq.size
```

Comment: Thank you but that was not what I asked for :)

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm to resolve that is the following:

- extract an Array of the digits of your number.
- find all combinations you're interrested in within this array (using `Array#each_cons`)
- compute the product of each of those combinations
- check wether those products are uniques.

Here is an example of implmentation:

```
def colors(number)
  digits = number.digits
  (1..digits.length).map do |len|
    digits.each_cons(len).map { |slice| slice.inject(:*) }
  end.flatten
end

def is_colorful_number?(number)
  number_colors = colors(number)
  number_colors.length == number_colors.uniq.length
end

p is_colorful_number? 263
p is_colorful_number? 236
```

Comment: Thank you but that was not what I asked for :)